# Granting Advisor Privileges to HR unlocked in PDBORCL

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Oracle. I have HR schema in "PDBORCL" .
But it is not granted with "ADVISOR PRIVILEGE". 
I have tried to give it "ADVISOR PRIVILEGE" by using:

```
Data connection-> Privileges in VS2015
```

but it is giving me error as "INSUFFICIENT PRIVILEGES" .
How should I grant all privilege to HR using cmd?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the PDB as SYSDBA.

```
sqlplus sys@orclpdb as sysdba
```

Then grant the required privilege to the user.

```
SQL> grant advisor to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn hr@orclpdb
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select * from session_privs;

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
CREATE SESSION
CREATE TABLE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
CREATE TYPE
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE
SELECT ANY DICTIONARY

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
ADVISOR
SET CONTAINER

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```